# Как хранить результаты рейтинга комментариев?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть таблица с комментариями, им пользователь может поставить плюс или минус, затем после обновления страницы соответственно плюс или минус у данного комментария должен быть подсвечен, как правильно хранить эту информацию? Учитывая что объемы комментариев и голосов большие.

Comment: большие это сколько? тысячи миллионы или более?

Comment: очевидно что таблица юзер-комментарий-голос. больше никак.

Comment: Я бы еще составной индекс добавил в порядке комментарий-юзер-голос. Но лучше создать таблицу, наполнить и погонять разные варианты, изучая план запроса и какой индекс оказался эффективнее.